# Mysql database Inner Join query Give Error

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

sql database three table used inner join but its give error. Error shown in image.I don't Know whats the Problem.

[image]

Regserver.php

```
<?php

include 'Connection.php';

$reg = $_GET['reg'];

$sql = "select RegNo,a.RollNo,b.Standard,b.stdid,c.DivisionID,c.Division,Std_Name as StudentName,Std_Address,DOB,ContactNo1 as FatherNo,ContactNo2 as MotherNo, 
                                     School_Name as SchoolName,Decide_Fees as DecideFees,ImagePath 
                                     from Std_Reg as a inner join StandardMaster as b on a.Standard = b.stdid 
                                     inner join DivisionMaster as c on a.Division =c.DivisionID 
                                     where RegNo= '$reg'";
//$sql = "select * from Std_Reg";
$stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);

do {
    while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)){
       $result[] = $row; 
    }
} while (sqlsrv_next_result($stmt));

if(count($result)>0)
{
    $result1['status']=1;//"Login successfully";
    array_push($result,$result1);
}
else
{
     //$result[]="null";
    $result1['status']=0;//"Record not found";
    array_push($result,$result1);
}
sqlsrv_free_stmt($stmt);
sqlsrv_close($conn); //Close the connnectiokn first

echo json_encode($result); //You will get the encoded array variable

?>
```

Comment: can u post error message as text ?

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: result in C:\wamp\www\Project\Regserver.php on line 21

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: result in C:\wamp\www\Project\Regserver.php on line 21

Comment: Warning: array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in C:\wamp\www\Project\Regserver.php on line 30

Comment: is it mysql or sql server ?

Comment: define $result = []; before do loop.

Answer (score 0):

Error said you didn't defined variable

try to declare it before using

Prior to PHP 5.4:

`$myArray = array();`

PHP 5.4 and higher

`$myArray = [];`

told us me if this won't work for u.

Comment: this solution not working. i think query syntax error

Comment: because this code used in early php file used is execute succesfully

Comment: only query is different.